# Static analysis strange result

Tags: c, clang

I was investigating the use of magic numbers and I have simplified my experiment to the following program. I noticed that when I use the static analysis function in Xcode I get the message "Left operand of '==' is a garbage value" for the `temp[4]` comparison. Is this a false positive and if so why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *input;

  if(!(input = fopen("unknown_video.ext", "rb")))
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);

  int test_size = 10;

  int b = 0;
  int temp[test_size];

  while(b < test_size)
  {
    if((temp[b] = fgetc(input)) == EOF)
      break;

    b++;
  }

  fclose(input);

  if((temp[0] == 'R') && (temp[1] == 'I') && (temp[2]  == 'F') && (temp[3]  == 'F'))
  {
    printf("RIFF\n");
  }
  else if((temp[4] == 'f') && (temp[5] == 't') && (temp[6] == 'y') && (temp[7] == 'p'))
  {
    printf("QuickTime\n");
  }

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: int temp[test_size] = {0}; //Initializes the whole array to 0

Comment: @SteveCox Variable size objects cannot be initialised this way (according to clang, anyway)

Comment: yes they cant. variable size arrays cant be declared that way either in some compilers (or they at least give warnings). I thought clang was actually one of those compiler. if its variable length you should definitely just do int *temp = calloc(test_size, sizeof *temp);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All values in your temp array are potentially unitialized.

Looking at the lines

```
while(b < test_size)
{
  if((temp[b] = fgetc(input)) == EOF)
    break;

  b++;
}
```

we have the possibility that `fgetc` returns `EOF` immediately, thus making all the following tests test against uninitialized values.

The easiest way to solve this is to initialize the temp array.

Comment: Thank you, this killed the warning. My assumption was that the file is at least 10 bytes in size but I guess not the analyzer's. Curious why it didn't flag at `temp[1] == ...` though.

Comment: @koan It doesn't flag any of the first line because no comparison on that line will proceed past an EOF -- an EOF at any index 0-3 will cause the whole statement to fail and fall to the `else if`. Also, if you click the diagnostic, Xcode should show you its flow of logic in a similar way to this from clang's scan-view script: http://i.imgur.com/3Y4Z1iA.png

Comment: @tab Yes, but that logic flow doesn't explain why it didn't flag earlier. But as you explain, if [0] is an EOF then the rest of the line is ignored otherwise there could be uninitialised values when analysing the next line.